# I want error object in a parent from child in formk?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik, yup

It is my parent component

```
 <FormContainer
            initialFieldValues={id != undefined ? cvRecord : cvFormFields}
            formData={getFieldsByCategory(cvFormFields, selectOption.type)}
            formValidation={cvFormFields}
            // onFormSubmit={onFormSubmit}
          >
            {/* button group */}
            <div className="text-md-end mt-5">
              <button className="btn btn-primary ms-2 mb-2" type="submit">
                Save <i className="bi bi-file-earmark-fill" />
              </button>

              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-danger ms-2 mb-2"
                data-bs-toggle="modal"
                data-bs-target="#cvdownloadmodal"
              >
                <i className="bi bi-eye me-1" />
                Preview and Download
              </button>
            </div>
          </FormContainer>
```

and this is child component

```
import { Form, Formik, useFormikContext } from "formik";
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import GenerateFields from "./GenerateFields";
import { getFormInitialValue, getFormValidations } from "./utility/formUtils";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const FormContainer = ({
  initialFieldValues = [],
  formData = [],
  onFormSubmit = "",
  formValidation = [],
  extraInputClass = "",
  children,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  // Toggle Validations
  const withValidation = formValidation ? true : false;

  // Get form Initial Value
  const initialValues = Array.isArray(initialFieldValues)
    ? getFormInitialValue(initialFieldValues)
    : initialFieldValues;

  // Get Form Validaton Schema
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape(
    getFormValidations(formValidation)
  );

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={withValidation ? validationSchema : ""}
      onSubmit={
        onFormSubmit
          ? onFormSubmit
          : (val, { errors }) => {
              console.log(" ~ file: FormContainer.jsx:38 ~ val", errors);
              setFormValues([...formValues, val]);
            }
      }
      enableReinitialize={true}
    >
      {(formAttributes) => (
        <Form className="formikContainer row m-2">
          {formData.map((fieldAttribute, index) => {
            return (
              <GenerateFields
                key={index}
                inputAttributes={fieldAttribute}
                formActions={formAttributes}
                withValidation={withValidation}
              />
            );
          })}
          {children && children}
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default FormContainer;
```

and this is my output

[my result screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ailow.png)

Now I want to get an error object in a parent component that was used to show a red area in which validation is required like if the user only enters the basic info and tries to submit the form then the remaining section becomes red because the user leaves the field empty in the remaining section. Anyone has any idea how to tackle this problem?

I expect the logic which is helpful in my project

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

function ChildrenComponant({ setError }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* error from formik */}
            {({ error }) => {
                setError(error)
            }}
        </div>

    )
}

function Parent() {
    const [error, setError] = useState({ message: "" })
    useEffect(() => {
        // some function or re-render logic after error change
    }, [error])

    return (
        <div>
            {/* show error message */}
            <div>{error.message}</div> 
            {/* Passing setError prop to child so that error can be set from children and accessed in parent */}
            <ChildrenComponant setError={setError} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```